# git-crypt path on MacOSX

Tags: macos, git, encryption, osx-mavericks

I have installed git-crypt (https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt) on Windows and it's work fine.

But when i try on MacOSX (Mavericks), it's not successful.

From the guide this command on Linux:

```
$ sudo ln -s "$(pwd)/gitcrypt" /usr/local/bin/gitcrypt
```

But i can not make it work on MacOSX.

I also try this command without success:

```
sudo -s 'echo "/usr/local/bin/gitcrypt" > /etc/paths.d/$(pwd)/gitcrypt'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. I post here for anyone find it:

```
 $ clone https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt /usr/local/git-encrypt
 $ sudo vi /etc/paths
```

Add /usr/local/git-encrypt to the end save and quit terminal.